# Irreducibility of a polynomial linked to his reduction mod $m$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Assume to have a domain $D $, consider a maximal ideal $m$, take $f \in D[X]$ and take $\overline{f}\in (D/m)[X]$ (which is a field) s.t. $\overline{f}$ is irreducible. 
In this situation in which hypothesis $f$ is irreducible?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: No other hypothesis, either on $D$ or on $f$?

Comment: i mean what i have to add to $D$ yes

Comment: Such questions are difficult to answer unless you have some answer you are seeking. One easy case is, if no non-unit divides all the coefficients of $f$ and $\deg f=\deg \overline{f}$.

Comment: @Mohan i know unfortunately i'm searching to understand a proof in which this fact it used but i don't understand why it is true

Comment: First, if this is what you wanted, it would have been better to say so than wording the question the way you have.  Just by definition, if $f(X)$ is not irreducible, one can write $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$. Now, what does it say modulo the maximal ideal?

Answer (score 0):

This is true (**with the additional assumption that the leading coefficient of $f$ is not in $m$**). It is a special case of the result

> Let $I$ be a proper ideal in the integral domain $R$ and let $p(x)$ be a nonconstant monic polynomial in $R[x]$. If the image of $p(x)$ in $(R/I)[x]$ is irreducible, then $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Let's modify the standard [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010125/reducible-in-rx-implies-reducibility-in-r-ix) to your case:

Take $f \in D[X]$ with the leading coefficient of $f$ not in $m$. Suppose $f$ is reducible, but $\bar{f} \in (D/m)[x]$ is irreducible. Then $f=gh$ with $g,h$ not units. Now the leading coefficient of both $g$ and $h$ cannot be in $m$ (otherwise their product would be in $m$, which is not true by assumption). So $\bar{g}$ and $\bar{h}$ both have degree greater than one. Then we have a nontrivial factorization $\bar{f}= \bar{g} \bar{h}$. Contradiction. So $f$ was irreducible.

---

Notice that we need the assumption that the leading coefficient of $f$ is not $m$, or else it can easily be the case that either $f$ or $g$ is a unit in $(D/m)[x]$ and our proof doesn't work.

For an example where we don't enforce the leading coefficient condition: Take $f = 2x^2+x-1$. Then $\bar{f} = x+1$ mod $2$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$. But $f$ was reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$: $f = (2x-1)(x+1)$.